# How to categorize the values of a large data set in R?

Tags: r, large-data, survey

I got a large-scale data set. One of my variables is "postal code". For this one, participants were able to enter their postal code of residence.

Now, I want to use the if...else function to search for postal codes that are located in the city and put them in a new variable with the name "city". Postal codes that do not match the city postal codes should be analyzed for character length --> if they have more than 4 characters, I will exclude them. The remaining postal codes participants reported will be labelled as "rural" since they are valid but not located in a city.

So far so good.

However, I can't really create an if-loop that is actually working.

Imagine my variable to look like this:

```
show(data_participants$location)

[1] 3324 3345 0000 33876 5499 8999 7634 1055 1188 8484
[2] 7788 RTIR 8393939484 1183 9993 9992 3832 4464 55938 8392     #same amount of values per row (this one just sticks out because of a long, invalid postal code)
```

and so on...

What I tried so far:

```
enter code here: library(dplyr)
enter code here: city_life <- ifelse(data_participants$location %in% c(3324|7788|3832),1,0)
```

Or I am thinking about something like this:

```
location <- c(data_participants$location)
ifelse(location == 3324){
       print("city")}
 else if (location==7788){
        print("city")}
 else if (location==3832){
       print("city")}
 else {
       print("No city but we need to test if it's a village")}
```

Followed by creating a subset of answers == "city".

I also factorized the data but I have now clue how to efficiently extract data from the huge amount of postal codes. I never used if...else functions in R.

Comment: Use `if_else` or `case_when` or you should create a map and write a "replacer" based on that map.

Comment: `city_life <- data_participants$location %in% c(3324, 7788, 3832)` gives you a logical vector of TRUE, FALSE or `city_life <- as.integer(city_life)` will make it 1 or 0. This would be much faster than `ifelse()`.